# Laravel: query a model with count

Tags: php, laravel, count, model

how can query in laravel with model method ?
i have a counter method in city model and i want to use this in my select query in response

how can i write this ?

my City model

```
public function mobile()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Mobile::class);
}

public function mobile_count()
{
    return $this->mobile()->count();
}
```

my query

```
public function findCityWithID($id)
{
    $subgroup = City::select('id', 'name', 'state_id')->where('state_id', $id)->orderBy('name')->get();
    return response()->json($subgroup);
}
```

i want have in $subgroup each City mobile counts

Comment: You don't need a `mobile_count()` method, you can just use `->withCount('mobile')`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Model:

```
public function mobiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Mobile::class);
}
```

The Query:

```
$cities = City::withCount('mobiles')->where('state_id', $id)->get();

$response[];
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    response[
      'id' => $city->id;
      'name' => $city->state;
      'state_id' => $city->state_id;
      'mobile_count' => $city->mobile_count;
    ];
}

return response()->json($response);
```